# GDB does not display the value of global variables

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have three files, TDS.c, TDS.h, ExtraRoutines.c which are compiled together as a shared library. TDS.h is the header file and defines the variables. ExtraRoutines.c is responsible for memory allocation, and TDS.c performs the main job.
A variable x0 is defined in TDS.h as `double* x0`, to which the memory is allocated in ExtraRoutines.c as

```
x0 = malloc(10 * sizeof(*x0));
```

At the first Line of TDS.c, I call ExtraRoutines.c to allocate the memory. The memory allocation is performed as normal and the function returns. The problem pops up when I use gdb to debug the program. When I use `print x0[0]` to access the data, it says:

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

which implies that `x0` is `NULL`. But I am pretty sure that `x0` is not `NULL` because,  when I use the following commands to save the data of `x0` into a file, the correct values are saved which implies that `x0` exists and refers to a valid memory address.

```
FILE* fh = fopen("dump", "w");
for(k = 0; k < 10; k++)
{
    x0[k] = orgX0[k];
    fprintf(fh, "%f\n", x0[k]);
}
fclose(fh);
```

The program has a bug and I need to find the bug by analyzing the data. Since currently `gdb` does not show any of the global variables, it is very hard to find the bug. So, it is appreciated to help find the problem and display the value of global variables (including x0) in gdb.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe `double *x0` is being initialized, but `orgX0[k]` is `NULL`. How is `orgX0[k]` being initialized?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. orgX0 is a variable being passed to TDS.c by another function and it is not Null. I can see the contents and also the memory to which it addresses. The memory address is: $3 = (const double *) 0xae0a3820 and also the contents are fine and the same as I expect.

Comment: using a short name such as x0 for a global variable is a bit dangerous, it's easy to unintentionally shadow that variable. Also, are you sure you've not defined the variable as `static` ?

Comment: Are you sure that the memory allocation routine has returned at the point you query `x0`'s value? Also, since it is a shared library, are you sure that at the point of debugging, you are linking in the shared library you are debugging, and not some older one from a previous build?

Comment: One final comment, are all your source files in your shared library compiled with `-fpic` or `-fPIC`?